# changing LUA_PATH in torch

Tags: lua, torch

I have two lua programs `main.lua`, `module.lua` in my directory `/home/user/lua`. I want to run `main.lua` while I am in a different directory: `/home/user`. So I add the following in LUA_PATH

```
export LUA_PATH=$LUA_PATH:/home/user/lua/?.lua
```

When I do :

```
/home/user$ th /home/user/lua/main.lua
```

I get error that `module.lua not found`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Lua looks for modules in а variable package.path. Add your directory:  package.path = '/home/user/lua/?.lua;' .. package.path

Comment: You mean inside torch code, I should modify package.path? Is there a way to work using the environment vars ?

Comment: Show us the values of `LUA_PATH` and the contents of `/home/user/lua/main.lua` where you load `module.lua`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use semicolon instead of colon to separate values of LUA_PATH variable.

```
export LUA_PATH="$LUA_PATH;/home/user/lua/?.lua"
```